# Google Master Tool: How allow external links in robots.txt

Tags: google-maps, robots.txt, googlebot

I have problem with google rendering.

Googlebot couldn't get all resources for this page. Because its blocked by its own google robots.txt

Here's an example of external link.
https://www.google.com/maps/vt?

https://www.google.com/robots.txt
[image]

Can I allow this in my website using my own robots.txt? So I can avoid the error.

Comment: This question's probably better on [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is: not possible. If Google does not want to index such pages in its `robots.txt`, then you can't force Google to do it.